# How to remount audio and midi drivers on MacOS BigSur to recognise audio interface?

Tags: macos-big-sur, input-devices

I got a question that Chat GPT can't seem to help me with

If I dont restart my macbook (Big Sur), my eleven rack audio interface will not be recognised. I dont want to have to restart my computer everytime i want to plug in my eleven rack audio interface. How I could more efficiently deal with this issue through terminal?

I've already tried

```
sudo killall coreaudiod
```

and

```
sudo kextunload -b com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHostCompositeDevice
sudo kextload -b com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHostCompositeDevice
```

These commands are executed but my audio interface is not recognised (unless I restart my com)

I guess I have the energy saver option to still try but honestly this shouldn't be that hard to remount drivers etc. It's super annoying to have to restart every single time I want to record something... especially when I am in the middle of something.

If anyone has figured out how to sort this out, I would love to hear from you